# Preview like sushi for Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, previews, gnome-sushi

I'm installing a Kubuntu 20.04 LTS system on a notebook and searching for a fast previewer like [gnome-sushi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_sushi) (more). 
Using this extension allows you to select a file in Nautilus, hit the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and it will show a quick preview.

Are there any alternatives or setups in dolphin I'm missing in Kubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: No, but you can use GNOME Nautilus+Sushi in a Plasma Environment too, you know.